# Will I run double-NAT with this configuration?

Tags: networking, router, modem, isp

My ISP has provided me with a VDSL2 router/modem with VoIP functionallity 
(Technicolor TG788V v3). Problem is that I want to connect my own router to the network. I contacted my ISP and they told me to disable my Internet Access on their hardware and keep the broadband and the telephony on. DHCP was on. Then they instructed me to connect one of the Technicolor LAN ports over to my router's WAN port and make a PPPoE connection using their credentials. My router received the ISPs IP. As far as I am concerned this is not double-NAT or is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in your case the Technicolor modem is in bridge mode (*just* a modem), indicated by facts that you're using PPPoE (which almost always goes to ISP's remote equipment instead of being local) and that your router is assigned a public address by the ISP.